# Find $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan(e^x)$

Tags: limits

> Find the limit $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\arctan(e^x)$$

I have no idea how I would solve it while showing all the steps.

I think the answer should be $\cfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

When  $x$ approaches $\infty$, $e^x$ also approaches $\infty$. So, what is the angle $\theta$ such that the value of its tangent approaches $\infty$ ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\arctan e^x=\arctan(+\infty)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
and
$$\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\arctan e^x=\arctan(0)=0$$